# I cannot install ffmpeg-light on Windows 10

Tags: haskell, ffmpeg, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install ffmpeg-light with Stack, but pkg-config was not found. I'been searching for people with the same problem but none of the answers seemed to fix my problem. This is the output I get whenever I try to install. If someone could help, I would be really happy.

```txt
ffmpeg-light              > configure
ffmpeg-light              > Configuring ffmpeg-light-0.14.0...
ffmpeg-light              > Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7.exe: The program 'pkg-config' version
ffmpeg-light              > >=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found.
ffmpeg-light              >
Progress 28/29

--  While building package ffmpeg-light-0.14.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7.exe
--builddir=.stack-work\dist\274b403a configure
--user
--package-db=clear
--package-db=global
--package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\pkgdb
 
--libdir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\lib
--bindir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\bin
--datadir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\share
--libexecdir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\libexec
--sysconfdir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\etc
--docdir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\doc\ffmpeg-light-0.14.0
--htmldir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\doc\ffmpeg-light-0.14.0
--haddockdir=C:\sr\snapshots\47171dc1\doc\ffmpeg-light-0.14.0
--dependency=JuicyPixels=JuicyPixels-3.3.6-GbCUJadIydOKYshnpdm9Pc
 
--dependency=base=base-4.14.3.0
--dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.12.0
--dependency=either=either-5.0.1.1-FfDF8totHqzHXhibaxp0YK
--dependency=exceptions=exceptions-0.10.4
--dependency=mtl=mtl-2.2.2
--dependency=stm=stm-2.5.0.1
--dependency=transformers=transformers-0.5.6.2
--dependency=vector=vector-0.12.3.1-2QhxFayEJrmJ3PNYTgAmQ3
-f-buildaudioextractdemo
-f-buildaudiosindemo
-f-builddemo
-f-buildrasterdemo
-f-buildtranscodedemo
-f-buildvplaydemo
--extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\anaca\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20210604\mingw64\include
--extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\anaca\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20210604\mingw64\lib
--extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\anaca\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20210604\mingw64\bin
--exact-configuration
--ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: pkg-config is an auxiliary tool used to check for non-Haskell dependencies (cf. [the relevant entry in the Cabal user guide](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-package.html?highlight=pkg-config#pkg-field-pkgconfig-depends)), such as the FFMPEG libraries needed by ffmpeg-light . The most sensible way for you to install pkg-config and those non-Haskell dependencies is through the MSYS2 environment that accompanies Stack (on that, see [*Developing on Windows*](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/developing_on_windows/) in the Stack user guide).

Answer (score 2):

As @duplode pointed out in a comment, Stack expects `pkg-config` to be already installed on your system.

As you are running Windows, stack packages an MSYS2 environment. MSYS2 uses the `pacman` package manger.

You can access the MSYS2 environment by prepending `stack exec --` to any command.

So running

```
stack exec -- pacman -S pkg-config
```

and then re-running Stack should solve your problem.